# Laravel 5.7 - Markdown Notification Undeclared Variable Exception

Tags: php, notifications, markdown, laravel-5.7

I recently upgraded from Laravel 5.6 to 5.7.

I updated a markdown notification view template by adding a new variable as follows:

```
$mailMessage = (new MailMessage)
        ->from('no-reply@xyz.com', 'xyz company')
        ->subject('xyz subject')
        ->markdown('emails.news-alert', [
            'url' => 'www.xyz.com',
            'articles' => $this->articles
        ]);


return $mailMessage;
```

inside the view `emails.news-alert` I have the following:

```
<a href='{{ $url }}'>{{ $url }}</a>
```

The notification is sent to a laravel queue but it keeps faling. When I check the `failed_jobs` table the exception is logged as:

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: url in storage\framework\views\b3a65990593f44f6fa9a99a22b876723bd86dd3b.php:38
```

I've tried clearing the cache but I'm still getting this error:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Strangely if I preview the notification as follows it displays fine:

```
Route::get('/notification', function () {


   $articles = App\Article::paginate(2);

   $message = (new App\Notifications\NewsNotification($articles))->toMail(Auth::user());

   $markdown = new Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown'));

   return $markdown->render('emails.news-alert', $message->data());

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restarting the queue:worker seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Had the same problem and this fixed it. Strange.